# How should I weight an N-gram sentence generator so that it doesn't favor short sentences?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp

I'm playing around with writing an n-gram sentence comparison/generation script. The model heavily favors shorter sentences, any quick suggestions on how I might weight it more towards longer sentences?

Comment: Probably the model contains an end of sentence symbol.  Reduce its weights.  Alternatively, add in more copies of longer sentences to its training data.

Comment: Was there supposed to be more text after "because"?

Comment: @DonReba No sorry accidentally left that in while editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you compute a score for each n-gram and rank the ngrams by these scores, you can adjust the scores of these n-grams by applying a different scalar weight for each value of `n`, e.g., `v = <0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0>`, where `v[0]` would be applied to an n-gram where `n == 1`.  Such a vector could be determined from a larger text corpus by measuring the relative frequencies of a set of representative solution n-grams (e.g., if you are looking for sentences, then calculate `n` for each sentence, count the frequencies of each value of `n`, and create a [probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) from that data.